# Indexer of IDataErrorInfo doesn't raise while texting to an (int)-Textbox

Tags: c#, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I can not check if the user set some text into a textbox which is bound to an integer-value. If the user sets numbers everything is ok. In case of negative numbers red borders are appearing outside of the textbox and the OK-button grays out. In case he sets text into the textbox the textbox is also red, but the OK-button doesnt grays out.

[image]

I got the following textbox and button

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ObjectModel.Length, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" x:Name="textBox_Length" />

<Button x:Name="button_applyChanges" Content="Speichern" Command="{Binding ObjectModel.OkCommand}" />
```

My model is the following:

```
public class ObjectModel : BaseModel
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "{0} can't be empty.")]
    [Range(typeof(Decimal), "0", "100000000", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a decimal/number between {1} and {2}.")]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand OkCommand { get; private set; }

    protected override void InitCommands()
    {
        base.InitCommands();
        OkCommand = new RelayCommand(
            () =>
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("OK");
            },
            () => IsOk);
    }

    protected override void OnErrorsCollected()
    {
        base.OnErrorsCollected();
        OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

At the basemodel i am including IDataErrorInfo and INotifyPropertyChanged. I got the following methods for the indexer-call, but the indexer-call doesnt raise on text-input...

```
    public virtual string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            CollectErrors();
            return Errors.ContainsKey(columnName) ? Errors[columnName] : string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void CollectErrors()
    {
        Errors.Clear();
        PropertyInfos.ForEach(
            prop =>
            {
                var currentValue = prop.GetValue(this);
                var requiredAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>();
                var maxLenAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
                var numericAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<RangeAttribute>();

                if (requiredAttr != null)
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty))
                        Errors.Add(prop.Name, requiredAttr.ErrorMessage);

                if (maxLenAttr != null)
                    if ((currentValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty).Length > maxLenAttr.Length)
                        Errors.Add(prop.Name, maxLenAttr.ErrorMessage);

                if (numericAttr != null)
                {
                    var result = 0;
                    var resultBool = Int32.TryParse(currentValue.ToString(), out result);

                        if(result <= 0 || !resultBool)
                            Errors.Add(prop.Name, numericAttr.ErrorMessage);
                }
                // further attributes
            });
        // we have to this because the Dictionary does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged            
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasErrors));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOk));
        // commands do not recognize property changes automatically
        OnErrorsCollected();
    }
```

I want the button to gray out while the user puts text into the textbox.

Comment: `Binding ObjectModel.Length` So, there's a property on the object within the DataContext of the Textbox called `ObjectModel`, that contains an ObjectModel instance, right?

Comment: The xaml of the usercontrol says the following: `<UserControl [...] DataContext="{Binding ObjectInspector, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">`
ObjectInspector (ViewModel) is initialized by the ViewModelLocator. The viewmodel holds the object "objectModel". 

 It s a bit complicated because of MVVM. Do u want me to add more code to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i finally got the solution... I changed the Length-type to string and solved it with regex.

ObjectModel:

```
    [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Must be a positive number")]
    public string Length { get; set; }
```

New CollectErrors()-method of basemodel:

```
    private void CollectErrors()
    {
        Errors.Clear();
        PropertyInfos.ForEach(
            prop =>
            {
                var currentValue = prop.GetValue(this);
                var requiredAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>();
                var maxLenAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
                var regexAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<RegularExpressionAttribute>();

                if (requiredAttr != null)
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty))
                        Errors.Add(prop.Name, requiredAttr.ErrorMessage);

                if (maxLenAttr != null)
                    if ((currentValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty).Length > maxLenAttr.Length)
                        Errors.Add(prop.Name, maxLenAttr.ErrorMessage);

                if (regexAttr != null)
                    if (!regexAttr.IsValid((currentValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty)))
                        Errors.Add(prop.Name, regexAttr.ErrorMessage);
            });
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasErrors));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOk));
        OnErrorsCollected();
    }
```